# How does starting Application Identity fixes start menu won't open issue

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1511

I'm running Windows 10 OS Version 10.0.10586 Build 10586
and  there's the bug when start menu, volume mixer, action center, wifi settings dialogs do not open when clicked on them. I've run across the following solution:

> Right-click at Start and click Run
>
> Type services.msc and press the Enter key
>
> Right click on Application Identity and select Start
>
> Reboot

and it helped. Is it possible to say what the problem was based on this fix that helped?

Comment: Do you have UAC disabled by chance?  Everything isn't working indicate either you have UAC disabled or you have severe system corruption.

Comment: You will need to some research on what UAC is, how it is disabled or enabled, before I can provide further assistance.

Comment: according to [this article](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-turn-off-and-disable-uac-in-windows-10/) UAC is not disabled on my PC

Comment: If it's not disabled then you have system corruption run SFC and DISM to, if it isn't that bad, fix the corruption.